LIS2DW12TR accerometer overheating massively when connected with I2C
I have 4 LIS2DW12TR accelerometers connected to an Seeed Studio ESP-32 S3. The accelerometers get extremely hot when they're connected to 3.3V. They are not recognised with an I2C scan.
The accelerometers are connected to 2 pairs of SDA/SCL pins. Each accelerometer has the same layout, save the SAO pin which sets the I2C address.They each have an LED connected to show that the accelerometers are on.
They're connected as follows:





The LEDs don't turn on but the accelerometers get extremely hot.
Thing's I've tried so far:

Did a continuity test with a multimeter (and very fine needles) - all the routes are connected as the schematics show, none are shorted.
Removed R9 - the accelerometer became even hotter.
Added a 27kΩ resistor to limit current to 100uA (data sheet asks for 90uA). I chose 27kΩ by measuring resistance between the 3.3V power route and the ground plane - it was 11kΩ. 27kΩ ≈ (3.3V/90uA) - 11kΩ

I'm not sure what else can be causing the over heating, or what i'm missing here. This is my first time wiring an IC, so all advice is super helpful!
EDIT: VDD_IO is connected to 3.3V by shunting pins 9 and 10 of each accelerometer (U1,2,3,4) together.

okay_computer - Hi (a) Please add photos of the hardware & wiring involved. To add photos using a PC (max 2MB each) press Ctrl+G while editing. On a touch device, click the "mountains" icon above the text entry area while editing. This will start the upload image dialog. (b) Have you made any voltage measurements to check the power rails & their polarity? (c) Perhaps there is no problem now, but you did something in the past & damaged component(s), causing excessive current. (d) "LEDs don't turn on" Investigate that, as diagnosis should be simple. (e) Update the question with results.

If the LEDs don't light, and the ICs are getting hot, I'd suspect that you have +3.3V and GND connections reversed.  Also, what is VDD_IO, and where is its source?

Seems that pull-up resistors are already wired on SCL, and SDA.

Is this a production board, or did you solder the components yourself? Are you sure that the component is mounted in the correct orientation? I seem to have a memory of a situation where a LIS2D-accelerometer were assembled 180 degrees wrong by the assembly house.
EDIT: They were assembled systematically incorrect, that is. Check the assembly drawing vs the package drawing to verify if the pin 1 orientation is clear.

Your diagram does not show what VDD_IO is connected to, VDD_IO must be 3.3V because on two of the accelerometers (U3,U4) you have 3.3V connected to SDO. Make sure VDD_IO is connected, the schematic shows it going to no VCC or what voltage level it's set to. (also you have what appears to be two sets of pullups on D3-SCL2 and pin 4 on U3 goes nowhere)
Since there isn't anything glaringly obvious, you may want to triple check your footprint and orentation of the parts and make sure the pins go to what you intend them to (this part is rotationally symmetrical when assembled so it could be easy to get it wrong

Addressing each point: a) VDD_IO is connected to 3.3V (addressed in edit), b) can you show me what you mean by 2 sets of pull ups? c) pin 4 of U3 was a labelling error which is now corrected.
